# One QuerySet for two tables (one to many related)

Tags: django, django-templates

I have created one to many relationship (two tables) such that every user has its own IP connections list. Every user has many connections.

My models are shown below:

```
class Conn(models.Model):
        src_ip = models.CharField(max_length=18, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        src_port = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        dst_ip = models.CharField(max_length=18, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        dst_port = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        proto = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        start_data = models.CharField(max_length=18, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        r_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class User(models.Model):
        e_user = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_dev = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_session = models.CharField(max_length=9, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_start = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_stop = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_summary = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
        e_ip = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False,default=None,blank=True,null=True)
```

I'm trying to get all `User`s with their connections (`Conn`) in one `QuerySet` and then display everything in template. So far I can display every User without any problems with

```
q=Users.objects.all()
```

and passing the `QuerySet` to the template.

The question may be a bit not smart but how can I query all `User`s including related connections (`Conn`) as one `QuerySet` and then enumerate this connections in a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
users = User.objects.all().prefetch_related('conn_set')
```

Now for each user you can look at its `conn_set` and see the `Conn` objects linked to it. Assuming you pass `users` to your template as a context variable `users`, something like this should work:

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ user.e_user }}

    {% for connection in user.conn_set.all }}
        {{ connection.src_ip }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Adjust fields and add other markup to suit your needs.

From the documentation, `prefetch_related`

> Returns a `QuerySet` that will automatically retrieve, in a single batch, related objects for each of the specified lookups.

If this had been a one-to-one relationship or if you'd been trying to look things up in the other direction, finding all `Conn` objects along with the related `User`, you could have used [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related), which is even more efficient.

Note that you can also clean up some of your fields by choosing more appropriate [field types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/). For example, consider [`GenericIPAddressField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#genericipaddressfield) for `src_ip` and `dst_ip`.